# Коротка запись условия if eleseif else в PHP

Tags: php, if

Пример:

```
if (isset($this->data) and !empty($this->data)) {
        
        $this->data();
        
    } elseif (!empty($this->data2)) {
        
        $this->data2();
        
    } else {
        
        $this->data3();
        
    }
```

Как реализовать короткую запись данного условия?

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: Никак и нет смысла

Comment: если бы if elseif else можно было реализовать короче, то реализовали бы

Comment: Обмажутся своими синтаксическими сахарами...

Comment: Можно. `$cond1 ? a() : ($cond2 ? b() : c());`, но особого профита в этом не вижу т.к. читаемость не улучшается, а падает. Проверять `isset` и `!empty` не имеет особого смысла, можно оставить только второе

Comment: ArchDemon, isset чтоб notice не вылазили мб

Comment: @Jour empty включает (! isset)

Answer (score -1):

Насколько я знаю,то возможен такой формат

```
  if (isset($this->data) and !empty($this->data)) $this->data();
   elseif (!empty($this->data2)) $this->data2();
    else $this->data3();
```

Comment: Ага, можно ещё в одну строчку тоже самое. это будет скоращённо? И по одной букве вместо переменных....